# react state change does not work as expected with dynamic function call - however if i use an input element to change same field state, it works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Hello i am trying to change the state of medicationRequest with function call, logs shows correct value is passed.

where medicationRequest is object of reducer

`const medicationRequest = useAppSelector((state) => state.medicationRequests.medicationRequest);`

when the form is submitted, i am displaying the current state on console log immediately before and after update

```
console.log("before update " , medicationRequest)
        dispatch(setMedicationRequest({ ...medicationRequest, ['requestStatus']: 'Completed' }));
        console.log("after update " , medicationRequest)
```

log response [before update requestStatus:Active, payload inside setMedicationRequest : Complete, after update requestStatus:Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MW4W.png)

reducer file code snippet

```
setMedicationRequest(state, action: PayloadAction<MedicationRequestData>) {
      console.log("payload inside setMedicationRequest " , action.payload)
      state.medicationRequest.requestStatus = action.payload.requestStatus;
      console.log("requestStatus inside setMedicationRequest" , state.medicationRequest.requestStatus)
    },
```

problem : state of requestStatus remains Active, expected value is Completed

if i use user input to change the state for requestStatus

```
 <Field as="select" className="form-control-solid form-select form-select-sm w-100" onChange={updateRequestInput} value={medicationRequest.requestStatus}  name="requestStatus" id="requestStatus" >
               <option value="Active">Active</option>       
               <option value="Partial">Partial</option>       
               <option value="Completed">Completed</option>              
                </Field> 

const updateRequestInput = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    dispatch(setMedicationRequest({ ...medicationRequest, [name]: value }));
  };
```

this works as expected, please see image attached - Row 6 is the result of user action change, and this somehow retains correct status inside submit logs
[correct status is maintained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcgrT.png)

using this user input is not correct solution as Active/Completed needs to be auto determined based on some checks

Both methods essentially call the same function in reducer to update so why does it work in one case and not the other?

EDIT 1 : added simplified code for clarity

dispense.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { useAppSelector,useAppDispatch } from "../../../hooks";
import { newMedicationDispense, setMedicationDispense, setSubmitted } from '../../../reducers/medicationDispense';
import { setMedicationRequest,setMedicationRequestStatus } from '../../../reducers/medicationRequest';

interface RouterProps { // type for `match.params`
  id: string; // must be type `string` since value comes from the URL
}

type Props = RouteComponentProps<RouterProps>;

export const PrescriptionDispense: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const medicationRequest = useAppSelector((state) => state.medicationRequests.medicationRequest);
  const submitted = useAppSelector((state) => state.medicationDispenses.submitted);

  useEffect(() => {
    retrievePrescription(props.match.params.id);
    dispatch(setSubmitted(false));
    dispatch(newMedicationDispense(medicationDispense));
  }, [props.match.params.id]);
  
  const updateRequestInput = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    dispatch(setMedicationRequest({ ...medicationRequest, [name]: value }));
    dispatch(setMedicationDispense({ ...medicationDispense, 'dispenseStatus': value }));
  };

  const saveMedicationDispense = () => {  
    MedicationDispenseService.create( medicationDispense)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setMedicationDispense(response.data));
        let disID = response.data.id;
        console.log("before update " , medicationRequest)
        dispatch(setMedicationRequest({ ...medicationRequest, ['requestStatus']: 'Completed' }));
        console.log("after update " , medicationRequest)
        MedicationRequestService.update(medicationRequest.id,medicationRequest)
        .then(response => {
          
        })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
          alert("Medication Dispensed Successfully");
          props.history.push('/prescription-dispensed-list/');
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
      
  };

  // get pricing id to use
  let pricing_id=''
  
  const retrievePrescription = (id: string) => {
    MedicationRequestService.getRequestInfo(id)
    .then(response => {
      if(response.data.list){
      PharmacyPricingService.getPricingByCompanyOrPharmacy(response.data.list.company_id,response.data.list.performer)
      .then(responsepricing => {
        pricing_id=responsepricing.data.id

        MedicationRequestService.get(id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("set medicationRequest with data from service response", response.data)
          dispatch(setMedicationRequest(response.data));
          console.log("after  set " , medicationRequest)
          setMedicationRequestOriginalStatus(response.data.requestStatus);

        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
    else{
      alert("Request already completed");
      props.history.push('/view-prescriptions/');
    }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    
  };
  
  return (  
    <Formik
    enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={{
    }}
    onSubmit={values => {

      let countTotal=0;
    medicationRequestItems.forEach((medicationRequestItem, i) => (
      countTotal = countTotal + Number(medicationRequestItem.quantity_dispensed)
    ));
    console.log("total count dispensed" , countTotal)
    dispatch(setMedicationDispense({ ...medicationDispense, 'dispensedCount': countTotal }));
    if(medicationDispense.requestedCount == medicationDispense.dispensedCount )
    dispatch(setMedicationDispense({ ...medicationDispense, 'dispenseStatus': 'Completed' }));
    else
    dispatch(setMedicationDispense({ ...medicationDispense, 'dispenseStatus': 'Partial' }));
    console.log("inside submit " , medicationDispense.requestedCount , " " , medicationDispense.dispensedCount)

    // try hardcoded value
    //updateRequest('requestStatus','Completed');
        saveMedicationDispense();
    }}
       >
         
         {({ setFieldValue }) => (
           <Form>
             {(isLoggedIn) && ( 
    <Styles>
  <Card>
        <Card.Header className="rvtd">
         Prescription Dispense
         {submitted ? (<p style={{ color : "green"}}>Record Successfully Added</p>) : ( <span></span>) }
        </Card.Header>  
       
        <Card.Body className="">
       various form elements here  
              
              Request Status
                 <Field as="select" className="form-control-solid form-select form-select-sm w-100" onChange={updateRequestInput} value={medicationRequest.requestStatus}  name="requestStatus" id="requestStatus" >
       <option value="Active">Active</option>       
       <option value="Partial">Partial</option>       
       <option value="Completed">Completed</option>              
        </Field> 
              
                 {medicationRequestOriginalStatus!='Completed' ? <Button className="fw-bold float-right" color="primary" >
              Dispense
</Button> : ''}
       
         </Card.Body>
 </Card>
 </Styles>
 )}
 </Form>
 
 )}
</Formik>
);
};
```

reducer medicationRequest.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import type MedicationRequestData from '../types/pharmacy/MedicationRequest';

export interface MedicationRequestState {
  medicationRequests: MedicationRequestData[],
  medicationRequest: MedicationRequestData,
}

const initialState: MedicationRequestState = {
  medicationRequests: [],
  medicationRequest: {id:"",requestId: "",requestStatus: ""},
};

const medicationRequestsSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: "medicationRequests",
  reducers: {
    newMedicationRequest(state, action: PayloadAction<MedicationRequestData>) {
      state.medicationRequest.requestId = "";
      state.medicationRequest.requestStatus = "";
    },
    receivedMedicationRequest(state, action: PayloadAction<MedicationRequestData[]>) {
        state.medicationRequests = action.payload;
      },
    setMedicationRequestStatus(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.medicationRequest.requestStatus  = action.payload;
      console.log("inside setMedicationRequestStatus " , state.medicationRequest.requestStatus)
    },
    setMedicationRequest(state, action: PayloadAction<MedicationRequestData>) {
      console.log("payload inside setMedicationRequest " , action.payload)
      state.medicationRequest.id = action.payload.id;
      state.medicationRequest.requestId = action.payload.requestId;
      state.medicationRequest.requestStatus = action.payload.requestStatus;
      console.log("requestStatus inside setMedicationRequest" , state.medicationRequest.requestStatus)
    }
  },
});
export const { newMedicationRequest, receivedMedicationRequest, setMedicationRequest, setMedicationRequestStatus } = medicationRequestsSlice.actions;
export default medicationRequestsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Are you using redux devtools to track the state? I can't really tell from the code you've provided but It's possible you'd need to re-select or re-render the component querying the state after you update it. Is the function call within a component?

Comment: i am using Chrome devtools / console.log for tracking. Please see the edit. Call is made on submit and then page will redirect to another page so re-render is not required. Actually that select input is a temp fix, that needs to be removed.

Comment: Definitely use the redux dev tools, reducers need to be pure functions and shouldn't have console.logs in them. redux devtools will show you every action that is dispatched, and how the state has changed. It's all recorded, so you can "go back in time" to see it happen again if you need to. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

When you use user input to change the state for requestStatus it gets UI update because you are updating it from the render method of react. But, when you are doing it programmatically from within a function, you are not doing so. Either call it from render method, or use it from a useEffect method to get the update.

Comment: Please see the edit. Call is made on submit and then page will redirect to another page so re-render is not required. Actually that select input is a temp fix, that needs to be removed.